# Smooth cursor movement on touchpad (Loki 0.4)

Tags: touchpad

I wanted to have a more smooth cursor movement while using touchpad, much like Windows (8.1 for that matter). Now it's very wobbly - when I put a finger on the touchpad, the cursor shakes randomly within a few pixel range, so I can't, for example, click precisely where I want. I've read somewhere that mousetweaks might resolve this, but I have no idea if it even works on elementary - and if it does, I can't seem to figure out how. I believe it worked somehow like this - it takes movements from a ~30ms (?) timespan, and inputs an average of these. I don't know if I can do it manually. Does anyone know anything about it?

Touchpad is standard SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad

edit: system info, per `inxi -b`:

> **System:**
>   **Kernel:** 4.4.0-38-generic x86_64 (64 bit) **Desktop:** Gnome **Distro:** elementary 0.4 loki
>
> **Machine:**
>   **System:** SAMSUNG **product:** 350V5C/351V5C/3540VC/3440VC **v:** P09ABE.012.
>   **Mobo:** SAMSUNG **model:** NP350V5C-S08PL **v:** BOARD 00 **Bios:** American Megatrends **v:** P09ABE **date:** 07/04/2013
>
> **CPU:**
>   **Dual core** Intel Core i5-3210M (-HT-MCP-) **speed/max:** 1466/3100 MHz
>
> **Graphics**:
>   **Card-1:** Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
>   **Card-2:** Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series]
>   **Display Server:** X.Org 1.18.3 **drivers:** ati,radeon,intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
>   **Resolution:** 1366x768@60.06hz
>   **GLX Renderer:** Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Mobile GLX **Version:** 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0

Comment: What hardware are you using? Can you describe the touchpad problem in a little more detail? Thanks!

Comment: @ryandebeasi, edited!

Comment: It seems like touchpad is controlled by the `xinput` command. man xinput and man libinput might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I did some things I'm not entirely sure about, but I think `sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput` did what I wanted. I also did `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` but I don't remember if I hadn't had that installed in the first place.

[Thanks to Jason Gambrel, btw.](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7939/way-to-enable-vertical-two-finger-scrolling-but-not-horizontal/8088)

Comment: That did not fix the issue for me. Running Dell Latitude E7440 and elementaryOS 0.4 (Loki) 64-bit. The issue with the wobbling mouse cursor is still present.

Comment: Well I'll be damned. The mouse wobbling is suddenly gone... after a PC reboot! Either that, or my laptop just needed a much appreciated break in the weekend. Holy crap, this is fantastic. Hereby giving you an upvote and thanks for the tip!